# Conversion of JSON array with ::text[] not working as expected

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using ::text[] to convert an array inside a JSON column, like in the example below:

Imagine sometable to have a JSON column called 'object' with a structure like the following:

```
{ "properties": ["string", "someotherstring"] }
```

I am querying the db like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db.sometable
WHERE 'string' = ANY (ARRAY[object -> 'properties']::text[]);
```

I am expecting `ARRAY[object -> 'properties']::text[]` to return some kind of list of strings, like the following:

```
{"string", "someotherstring"}
```

...but, after some debugging, I realized it's returning some wierd s*** like the following:

```
{"[\"string\", \"someotherstring\"]"}
```

Basically, it is treating the whole array as a string! What could be the cause?

PS: I understand that I should use other functions or filters, but the real query I'm working on is highly dynamic and way more complicated than the example I provided. ::text[] seems to be the only option I have

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am expecting ::text[] to convert a JSON array into a list of strings, but it is actually considering the whole array as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to convert the json to a Postgres array. You need a proper operator.

```sql
select * 
from sometable
where object -> 'properties' ? 'string';
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/n-QDbPrx)

Read about json functions and operators [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_array_elements_text` combined with `ARRAY` to convert a json array into list of text values `TEXT[]` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable
WHERE 'string' = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(object->'properties')));
```

This is another method for looking for an element within a json array :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sometable s, json_array_elements_text(object->'properties') as j
where j.value = 'string'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hYeJ1E1-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem

The table content: [a screenshot of the table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrvhm.png)

```
SELECT string_to_array(element, ',') AS string_array
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements_text(object -> 'properties') AS element
  FROM untitled_table_225
) subquery;
```

it gives the following output:

[a screenshot of the solution output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHUoE.png)

As you can see the records contain "{" and "}"; I simply removed them using `regexp_replace` function.

The SQL now being like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string_to_array(element, ',')::text, '\}|\{', '', 'g') AS string_array
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements_text(object -> 'properties') AS element
  FROM untitled_table_225
) subquery;
```

The results: [a screenshot of the final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEsoe.png)